# SwiperJS virtual slider displays blank slides for renderExternal with vueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, swiper.js

Trying to get virtual slides working with `swiper element` and vueJS.
But i am facing an issue, slides are not visible after initial few swipes.

I find no documentation example of how `renderExternal` is supposed to be used.

Here's my sample :  https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/frosty-rgb-cgkc94

```html
<template>
  <div class="screen">
    <swiper-container init="false" ref="swiperEl">
      <swiper-slide v-for="(q, i) in virtualSlides.slides" :key="q.id">
        <div class="card">
          {{ q.content }}
        </div>
      </swiper-slide>
    </swiper-container>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";

const slides = ref([]);

//cerate 50 slides
for (let i = 0; i < 50; i += 1) {
  slides.value.push({ id: i, content: `Slide ${i}` });
}

console.log("Slides", slides.value);

const virtualSlides = ref({ slides: [] });

const swiperOpts = {
  slidesPerView: 1,
  speed: 40,
  height: "100%",
  spaceBetween: 16,
  virtual: {
    slides: slides.value,
    addSlidesAfter: 0,
    addSlidesBefore: 0,
    initialSlide: 3,
    renderExternal: (data) => {
      console.log("Virtual data", data.slides);
      virtualSlides.value.slides = data.slides.map((s) => {
        return slides.value[s.id];
      });
      console.log("virtualSlide", virtualSlides.value.slides);
    },
  },
};

const swiperEl = ref();

onMounted(() => {
  Object.assign(swiperEl.value, swiperOpts);
  swiperEl.value.initialize();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Looks like a bug : I reported it here - https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/6454

Comment: Virtual module works with Swiper component Vue 3
V@2 S@9.4.1 ❌ https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-9-4-1-vue-2-bug-reproduction-3m84fx?file=/src/components/Gallery.vue
V@2 S@10 ❌ https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-10-vue-2-mhtmg2?file=/src/components/Gallery.vue
S@10 V@2 - CodeSandbox https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/swiper-vue-virtual-slides-v9-4-1-forked-nwz8wg?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue%3A1%2C1-70%2C1

V@3 S@ 9.4.1✅ https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/swiper-10-vue-3-6w46zc?file=%2Fpackage.json%3A8%2C36
V@3 S@10✅ https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/swiper-10-vue-3-6w46zc?file=%2Fpackage.json%3A8%2C36

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Vue and Swipe are fighting each other over rendering DOM inside swiper container when SwiperElement (web component) is used.

I've tried using both `virtual.renderExternal` and `virtual.renderSlide` to delegate rendering to Vue from SwiperElement, without much success. After all attempts, I've come to the conclusion that what you tried should have worked (because it does work when using same logic with React).

I was able to achieve the result you're looking for using the Vue components provided by `swiper/vue`. I know they're planned for deprecation in some future release, in favour of the web component API but, until the rendering issues with the virtual module are fixed, the Vue components seem to provide what you need.

[Demo here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/bitter-moon-e49yyr?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue).

---

Update:

Swiper's author answered the issue [here](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/6454#issuecomment-1471732495), providing an example.

I've tweaked it a bit [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/jovial-wind-4hhzvl?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue).

Relevant details:

- `:left` property on the slide element, using `offset`
- `initialSlide` moved outside of `virtual`

Comment: it doesnt work as expected, if you see in firebug, you will see tht all the 50 slides are rendered, it doesnt render slides on the fly as it gets scrolled

the purpose of renderExternal is to render just limited number of slides as they become visible, because there can be thousands

Comment: I see. That's a different problem, though. I'll have a look at swiper docs to see how `virtual` should be used.

Comment: Well, the slides are rendered by Vue, which renders what you tell it to: all 50 slides. You need to tell it to render less. I'll create an example.

Comment: Exactly, its about virtual slides to get working, otherwise i would just render all the slides and it works just fine, there;s no issue.

Try rendering slides only between virtualdata.from and virtualdata.to slides and i think you will encounter issue

Answer (score 0):

You should able to fix the issue by add the style with top or left with the given offset.

For vertical:

```
<li class="swiper-slide" style={`top: ${offset}px`}>
...
</li>
```

For default:

```
<li class="swiper-slide" style={`left: ${offset}px`}>
...
</li>
```

Comment: Did not work @smilefounder, could you fork my codesandbox and get it working ?

Comment: sorry, I have fixed it in svelte. I have tried to modify your code but not familiar with Vue. However, the offset value is not able to set into the style.left from your code. You can view from HTML DOM console and see all the values are left: 0px. That is why it not working. Please make sure the offset value can be set to the style of swiper-slide then it will work fore sure.

Comment: I think this solution works when swiper classes and elements are used direct. but not with swiper element.